# Trouble with compiling .cc files to be used in Intel Hyperscan

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-16.04

I am a student currently working on a project to implement Intel Hyperscan for Virus Signature Scanning on Ubuntu 16.04.

On the system, I have gcc 5.4.0 and g++ 5.4.0.
Hyperscan uses CMake to "build" itself.

Having successfully build Hyperscan, I can't seem to be able to find a way to compile my own code for it. I also could not find any "proper" way of compiling code meant for Hyperscan online, hence I assumed g++ would be right. I have tried,

> g++ -o -std=c++11 test test.cc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libhs)
>
> only for it to give the error: **hs.h: No such file or directory**
>   Hence I used,
>
> g++ -o -std=c++11 test test.cc -I../hyperscan/src $(pkg-config --cflags --libs
>   libhs)
>
> to get another error:
>   **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhs** and **collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

At this point, I am kind of lost and can't really progress with my project. Am I using g++ wrongly? Have I built Hyperscan incorrectly? Any tips or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(pkg-config --cflags --libs libhs) only works when library and related development files are installed on the system. Looks like you have source code of library, so first you need to build and install library itself, only then compile your test program.
Also, library may be available in standard repositories, then you maybe want to install it using something like "sudo apt install libhs-dev", however, if you have source code of particular version that you need to work with, or library is closed source and non-public, then the only way is to compile and install it manually. Refer to documentation, README, INSTALL files that may be supplied with library code and follow build and installation procedures described there.

Comment: Yes I have already compiled the source code for Hyperscan according to the documentation using CMake and verified that is works and exported "libhs.pc" to PKG_CONFIG_PATH. But I just can't seem to compile anything for it after that point. Even the example code which was provided could not be compiled manually using the command to compile it inside the README, giving the same errors.

Comment: But did you install headers and libraries to where they are supposed to be? if you open libhs.pc in text editor, you will see where they are expected. There must be some installation procedure in your build scripts that will expose already built library into system.

Comment: I.e. first you just build library, then you run additional command to install. For many libraries this is just "sudo make install" (sudo required because it will copy library files into system protected locations), but if you use cmake, there must be some similar command, however not sure which exactly. There must be something like this in your library too. I.e. just copying .pc into PKG_CONFIG_PATH doesn't work, because it will point to standard locations where it expects library to be installed.